# iOS 9.2.1: iBeacon region monitoring bug

Tags: iphone, ibeacon, beacon, ios9.2.1

I deployed the same iBeacon region monitoring [code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AirLocate/Introduction/Intro.html) in 7 devices. One of them, iPhone 6 running **iOS 9.2.1**, is regularly failing to detect beacon states (inside, outside, etc..).

I tried with and without **SIM** card and when the SIM card is inserted it gives better results. However, when compared to an iPhone 6 running **iOS 9.2.3** and one running **iOS 9.2.1** it gives worst results (the latter two iPhone's always detect the region).

- Have you experienced the same in this version of iOS (**iOS 9.2.1**)?
- Is this an known official Apple bug?

**My theory behind this:**

> iBeacon region monitoring uses iPhone location, iPhone location can be
>   improved using Wi-Fi and phone signal and possibly also accelerometer
>   and gyroscope data.
>
> iOS could be using these in combination withe the Bluetooth data to
>   "tune" the beacon ranging thread (in other words if a significant
>   location happens then the background monitoring frequency will be
>   increased). Hence if this tuning is depending on the SIM card
>   information there could be a version of iOS where they put a stronger
>   dependency on the SIM card presence leading to what I am observing.

Comment: Any theory about why a SIM card would make a difference?  (I would not think it should.)  Any specific reason to believe this is a OS version issue vs. a hardware issue?  It sounds like you are seeing it only on one physical device with 9.2.1, not two different devices with 9.2.1.

Comment: I have added theory